# Android webView - Can't load some links - Received RST for invalid stream

Tags: android, android-webview

I created a simple webView App which points to our onlineshop.

**Problem:**

We offer some files on our [Download page](https://www.blizz-z.de/downloads), but I can't download any of them via the App while it works with the smartphones Chrome browser.

**HTML:**

```
<a class="thirdbox" href="/media/wysiwyg/pdf/systemaufbau-anleitungen.pdf" target="_blank" download="blizz-z_Systemaufbau_Anleitungen" title="Datei downloaden">
<div class="iconlink">
    <p>Systemaufbau Anwendungsbroschüre<br><span style="font-size: 75%;">(PDF 5,8 MB)</span></p>
</div>
</a>
```

I am using this code, which also fixes the bug that links like `tel:` or `mailto:` can't get loaded.

But the function `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` is not getting entered if I click on a link on that page. I set a breakpoint at the log statement and it is never triggered.

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

    ...

    // Give the host application a chance to take control when a URL is about to be loaded in the current WebView.
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
    {
        Log.i("debug_log", "shouldOverrideUrlLoading");

    // Allow download of .pdf files
        if (url.endsWith(".pdf")) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
            // if want to download pdf manually create AsyncTask here
            // and download file
            return true;
        }

    // Allow URL's starting with /
        if (url.startsWith("/")) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(website + url)));
            // if want to download pdf manually create AsyncTask here
            // and download file
            return true;
        }

    // Also allow urls not starting with http or https (e.g. tel, mailto, ...)
        if( URLUtil.isNetworkUrl(url) ) {
            return false;
        } else {
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
        }

        return true;
    }

});
```

This is getting logged into the logcat console if I click on a file link:

> Received RST for invalid stream

Comment: What does "Received RST for invalid stream" even mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out that it is because of the html `download` tag
If I remove it, then It works because the webview does not support it.

```
<a class="thirdbox" 
   href="/media/wysiwyg/pdf/systemaufbau-anleitungen.pdf" 
   target="_blank" download="Systemaufbau_Anleitungen" title="Datei downloaden">...</a>
                       ↑
                    Problem
```